# Tab Index is not highlighting li instead of that it is highlighting the anchor tag inside that

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a Bootstrap dropdown, where I can fill list items dynamically through knockout foreach bindings.

Each li contains links (a tag) and also I've tab `index=0` for all list items.
I have styles for the `<li>` and anchor tag.

When I move the mouse over on `<li>`, it is changing the background color of `<li>`, when I use tab to move among list items, it is not changing background color of `<li>` instead of that I'm getting tab index effect on anchor tag.

The code is below.

```
<li class="lifecycle-state taskpanel-select-option" role="presentation" tabindex= "0">
    <a href="#" role="menuitem">
        <span data-bind="text: StateName"/>
        <span class="lifecycle-stateId" data-bind="text: StateId"/>
    </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the `:focus` styling in CSS.

```
a:focus,
a:hover { 
  // Your hover colour here will change the color for both hovering and when focused 
}
```

Best of luck :)